# Is there a way to control Rosetta Stone with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, rosetta-stone

I'm using the excellent Rosetta Stone for learning German. Problem is, in order to answer its language questions I'm forced to click the correct answer with the dreaded mouse. Is there any way to answer the quizzes using the keyboard?

**UPDATE:** Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot please of what the quizzes look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with Rosetta Stone and they said there is no keyboard support for these quizzes.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://jordan.husney.com/archives/2008/04/python_rosetta_stone_automatio.php) wrote a Python script that adds keyboard shortcuts to the windows version.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from msvcrt import getch

sys.path.append("../win32automation")

import win32automation

os.system("title KeySetta")
win32automation.spawnProcess(
    r"C:\Program Files\The Rosetta Stone\The Rosetta Stone\TheRosettaStone.exe")
while 1:
    print "Waiting for application to start..."
    result = win32automation.windowFocus("The Rosetta Stone")
    if result:
        print "Window found!"
        break
    time.sleep(1.0)
print "Waiting 5 seconds for login screen to appear..."
time.sleep(5.0)
win32automation.sendKeys('jordanh{ENTER}')

print """
   Keyboard to Mouse Macros Enabled:

     - Answer selection:
       [7] [9]
       [1] [3]

    Please focus this window to enable them...
"""

coord_map = {"7": (180, 300),
             "9": (480, 300),
             "1": (180, 475),
             "3": (480, 475)}

while 1:
    win32automation.windowFocus("KeySetta")
    ch = getch()
    print "Last key pressed: %s\r" % (ch),
    if ch in ('1','3','7','9'):
        win32automation.windowFocus("The Rosetta Stone")
        x, y = coord_map[ch]
        win32automation.mouseMoveToRelative("The Rosetta Stone", x, y)
        win32automation.mouseClick(button="left")
    elif ch.lower() == 'q':
        print "Quitting!"
        break
    else:
        print "WARNING: Unknown key-macro event '%c'." % (ch)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: It didn't work, I got a bunch of errors, one of them being an OSError on the `spawnv` action. I think this was intended for a really old version of Rosetta Stone.

Comment: Was worth a shot, I don't have Windows to try it out. Really wish Rosetta Stone would let me move more quickly.

Comment: Change the path to match: win32automation.spawnProcess(
    r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Rosetta Stone\Rosetta Stone Language Training\Rosetta Stone.exe")
This was my path for version 5.xx

Answer (score 0):

With [autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) you might be able to do that. 
With this script I am able to pause the screen I've just gone through with the escape key - in order to review new words, for example. (Rosetta makes you click on a tiny pause button, which is not very convenient)

```
#SingleInstance force
Escape::
{
    MouseGetPos X, Y    
    Click 836, 594 ; use WindowSpy to adjust numbers according to the window size
    MouseMove,  %X%, %Y%
}
return
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows accessibility options allow you to use the keyboard to control the mouse pointer. Maybe this may help if you are suffering from RSI, but the method is rather cumbersome.

It may be worth consulting the application vendor directly, or perhaps seeing if pressing the Tab key on your keyboards potentially offers a way to select an answer. The Tab key is generally the standard way of hopping between interface elements on Windows applications when using the keyboard.